# How do I use Action Invocation in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I am having trouble getting the IB Action Invocation to work when using the Argument bindings.  Can someone explain how this is meant to work.  If I don't use the Argument binding then the binding works but the method is called with a nil parameter.  I assume that the Argument binding is intended to set the parameter that will be passed in the method invocation.  In my case I want to get a reference to the Table Cell Views object.
I get a compiler error as follows:

```
Exception while running ibtool: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

I am binding the action invocation to a Button in the Table Cell View.

[image]

Comment: What you're doing looks right (but it's been a long time since I used cocoa bindings...).

Comment: Looks like a bug. Workaround: don't use the action binding and connect the action of the button to an action method that calls `cancel`.

Comment: @Willeke I was hoping to pass the objectValue as a parameter and that's not possible using the buttons action.  Also wanting to avoid subclassing the table cell view and using data source and delegate. The hack around is to force the user to select the table row before allowing the button to be clicked but that's not very efficient for the user.

Comment: Is it possible to add an action method to the delegate of the table view? In this action method you can get the object value and call `cancel`.

Comment: @Willeke not sure exactly what you mean, I am not using delegates or data sources but using NSArrayController directly as content for table view. Also not sure which delegate method you are referring to or how it would be invoked from the button action.

Comment: My workaround for now is to force the user to select an item and create a property observer on the NSArrayControler.selectionIndex property. ugly hack basically.

Comment: I logged a bug with Apple in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

In the Report Queue Table View Controller class:

- Add protocol `NSTableViewDelegate` to the declaration. You don't have to implement any methods.
- Add outlets for the array controller and the table view.
- Add an action method

```
@IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let row = tableView.row(for: sender)
    if let objects = arrayController.arrangedObjects as? [String] {
        let object = objects[row]
        cancel(object)
    }
}
```

In IB:

- Connect the outlets.
- Connect the delegate of the table view to the Report Queue Table View Controller.
- Connect the action of the button to `cancelAction` of the Report Queue Table View Controller.
- Remove the button action bindings.

Comment: Hmm, so the 'tableView.row(for: sender)' function will find row for the button, bearing in mind that there are a number of controls on the tableCellView in addition to the button?  I'll give this a try as it's a much more elegant approach.